# Mouse status info in python

Tags: python, cursor, mouse, pyautogui, status

I am using Python pyautoGUI to automate some steps to get a report from a software. When it runs the report, Python should wait for sometime until the report is ready. The wait time is not clear and it depends on many factors, like which report I am running, parameters of the report, as well as the internet speed. Processing time is from few seconds to hours. So, my python code cannot simply wait for a fixed amount of time. Instead, I am checking mouse cursor status to see when it changes from small blue circle (working status) to a small arrow (in Windows 10). I use win32gui.GetCursorInfo() to get the cursor status but I noticed that the cursor info for the arrow cursor status is not consistent. It is changing every time I run the code and it is not a fixed number.
How can I find out when my report is ready? Using pyauthoGUI.locateOnScreen() to find the image of cursor is not what I like to use.

Comment: I tried to use `win32gui.GetCursorInfo()` in a python shell and it seems to work consistently. With the normal cursor, I get `(1, 65541, (529, 67))` and with the text cursor it gives `(1, 65539, (529, 67))`. The first value is a boolean to tell you if the function succeeds and should normally be 1. The second value is what indicates which mouse icon is shown, and should be consistent across programs. Is this the value you're having trouble with?